# Is this integral inequality valid for all functions?

Tags: integration, inequality, definite-integrals, fractions

Is this true?:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\left|\int_a^bf\left(x\right)\cdot g\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x\right|^2}{\displaystyle\left|\int_a^bf\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x\right|^2}\le\int_a^b\left|g\left(x\right)\right|^2\space\text{d}x$$

(I think it is by the use of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality)

Comment: Do you mean $\overline{g(x})$ on the LHS? You need that for this to correspond to the C-S inequality.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not true for any set up where the bottom integral evaluates to $0$.